# How to get size of array in AWK?

Tags: awk, gawk

I have declared array by splitting string like below.

```
names = "Dhana,Subha,Siva"
n=split(names,name_arr,",");
```

I want to print the size of array here without using variable 'n'? is there any way similar to name_arr.length or name_arr.size() ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my GNU `awk` system following works, in case as per your question you don't want to use variable to get array's length. We could use `length` if it is available in your `awk`.

```
awk 'BEGIN{names="Dhana,Subha,Siva";split(names, array,",");print length(array)}'
```

Output will be `3`.

***Solution 2nd:*** In case you don't have `length` option in your `awk` and you don't want to use `num=split(..)` option then you have to do it in old way you have to iterate through array and get its count and finally print it then as follows:

```
awk 'BEGIN{names="Dhana,Subha,Siva";split(names, array,",");for(i in array){val++};print val}'
```